# tr -d not work with carriage return

Tags: shell-script

I want to get rid of \n from variable I found many answers for that which say "use tr -d" but `tr -d` not work for me

```
echo "$test" | od -c
0000000   4   4   2   5   2  \n
0000006
```

then I use `tr -d`

```
test2=$(echo $test | tr -d '\n')
```

but nothing change

```
echo "$test2" | od -c
0000000   4   4   2   5   2  \n
0000006
```

Comment: The `\n` seems to be a normal text element. Try with `tr -d '\\n'` which does not search for a new line but rather for the text `\n`.

Comment: `tr -d '\n' ` works fine. As user @user1700494 said, echo print arguments for stdout + newline. `echo -n` echo without newline.

Comment: The question title refers to a "carriage return" (\r), but the question itself is about newlines (\n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  of `tr -d '\n'` , removes `\n` (i.e. newline character) as expected. But you are verifying this with `echo` command. `Echo` command itself will put new line character @ end of input string and hence you are unable to see expected output.

Check variable with below set of commands.

```
test2=$(echo "$test" | tr -d '\n')
printf "%s" $test2 | od -c
echo -n $test2 | od -c
```

Script Output:

```
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
```

Note: 
echo -n : From echo man page : -n     do not output the trailing newline
printf  : does not append \n at end

Answer (score 2):

`echo` is appending `\n` by default. Use `-n` to omit

```
[6]root@lab7:~> echo 'lol' |od -c
0000000   l   o   l  \n
0000004
[6]root@lab7:~> echo -n 'lol' |od -c
0000000   l   o   l
0000003
```